# Wordpress plugin- need add PHP function

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

*Firstly, I am writing because I have excercise to do wordpress plugin, so this is why I am putting this code into wordpress plugin(I know the plugin idea is different).*
Okay so, I have code like this:

```
if($currentpage == $homepage or $currentpage == 'index.php') {   
      echo'


<html>
    <head>
        <style>

            .coupon {
    border: 5px #bbb;
    width: 60%;
    border-radius: 15px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    max-width: 900px;

}





.container {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.promo {
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 3px;
}

.expire {
    color: red;
}
        </style>
        <title>Konkurs Designerski</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="coupon">
  <div class="container">
    <h3><center>Zapraszamy do wzięcia udziału w konkursie</center></h3>
  </div>
  <img src="http://homeonthehill.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/jak-urzadzic-balkon-w-bloku-1.jpg" alt="kolor" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="container" style="background-color:white">
    <h2><b>Prosimy zgłaszać się do konkursu pod adresem mailowym konkurs@iwb.pl</b></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container">

    <p class="expire">Zgłoszenia prac konkursowych trawją do  26 kwietnia. Zasady w regulaminie na stronie głównej</p>
  </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
        ';
}
     else
     {

     }
?>
```

It works fine, but I NEED add some extra function(more advanced). 
So how I can define user, who is logged? I wanna make personalized container, like Hello $user(when he's logged in wordpress account or hello Anynomous for guest).
Really thanks for help

Comment: See this function to check if logged in user https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/ , then this function to get current user's info like name etc https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/

Answer (score 0):

It is needed to change this from echo all? It will works if i put it into this long echo statement?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below function to check user login.

```
<?php
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
       echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
   } else {
            echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
          }
?>
```